# Google Admin API to Restore Permanently Deleted Files

Tags: google-drive-api, google-admin-sdk

Is there a way to restore permanently deleted files in Google Drive via the API? I know that it is possible from the admin console, butI can't seem to find anything about an API to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to perform such action through the [`Admin SDK`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory) so at the moment you could only submit a feedback a feature request, you do this through an [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191635&template=824102). There is already a similar [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146166967) however there hasn't been any updates on it.